# Expanding-Collapsable HTML List- ul - li

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, collapsable

I am trying to implement an expand-collapse list of ul and li:
i am dynamically constructing the li from a json file, but couldn't make it collapsable.

I am trying with a static declaration first and then the dynamic one,
my JS collapsing code works with the static but not the dynamic :( don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
ul li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:10px;
} 

a {
    color: red;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window)
            .load(
                    function() {
                        var JSON = {
                            menu : [ {
                                name : 'Title',
                                link : '#',
                                sub : null
                            },{
                                name : 'Link',
                                link : '#',
                                sub : null
                            },{
                                name : 'Content',
                                link : '#',
                                sub : null
                            },{
                                name : 'Enclosures',
                                link : '#',
                                sub : [ {
                                    name : 'Enclosure1',
                                    link : '#',
                                    sub : null
                                }, {
                                    name : 'Enclosure2',
                                    link : '#',
                                    sub : null
                                }, {
                                    name : 'Enclosure3',
                                    link : '#',
                                    sub : null
                                } ]
                            }, {
                                name : 'Authors',
                                link : '#',
                                sub : [ {
                                    name : 'Author1',
                                    link : '#',
                                    sub : null
                                }, {
                                    name : 'Author2',
                                    link : '#',
                                    sub : null
                                } ]
                            },{
                                name : 'Published At',
                                link : '#',
                                sub : null
                            }, {
                                name : 'Stream',
                                link : '#',
                                sub : [ {
                                    name : 'STR1',
                                    link : '#',
                                    sub : null
                                }, {
                                    name : 'STR2',
                                    link : '#',
                                    sub : null
                                } ]
                            } ]
                        }

                        $(function() {

                            function parseMenu(ul, menu) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
                                    var li = $(ul).append(
                                            '<li class="content"><a href="'+menu[i].link+'">'

                                                    + menu[i].name
                                                    + '</a></li>');
                                    if (menu[i].sub != null) {
                                        var subul = $('<ul id="submenu'+menu[i].link+'"></ul>');
                                        $(li).append(subul);
                                        parseMenu($(subul), menu[i].sub);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            var menu = $('#menu');
                            parseMenu(menu, JSON.menu);
                        });
                    });//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="menu" class="list">
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.list > li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you meant by dynamic. There is a DOM tree and the collapse and expand will work based on that DOM tree.

Comment: Jijo Cleetus i edited the code, i just want to make the list than i am constructing with the json data collapsable.

Comment: I hope it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your static `.click()` bind to be dynamic

```
$(document).on('click', '.list > li a', function () {
    $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
})
```

---

When using `.event()` you declare event for all elements that currently is in DOM. Since you load your JSON and than append elements, your click event does not see new elements and does nothing (that's why it's working with pre-defined DOM).

When using `$('static-element-selector').on('event', 'dynamic-element-selector')` you bind event to static element *and* listen for newly added elements.

Comment: can u give a concrete example please ?

Comment: @AbderraoufBarrak Can you provide DOM structure after JSON loading?

Comment: what do you mean by DOM structure

Comment: @AbderraoufBarrak Literally what html you get after JSON append.